# How to get parents of custom taxonomy, as what get_category_parents() do?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, hierarchical

I have a custom taxonomy 'portfolio category', while i need to show all hierarchy categories of a portfolio post, for example

the post is under `topcat -> childcat -> yetchildcat`, i want to show 'topcat, childcat, yetchildcat' on the post page, but `get_the_terms only` return '`yetchildcat`', how do i get all?

Answer (score 2):

There is a more generic function: it's called `get_ancestors()` and it's found in `wp-includes/taxonomy.php`

Comment: Shiny... I keep coming upon nice new stuff in couple latest major releases.

Answer (score 1):

@Jeff,

Thanks for this. I fixed your broken $link function. and changed the defaults to include "»" as the separator.

```
// my own function to wo what get_category_parents does for other taxonomies
function get_taxonomy_parents($id, $taxonomy, $link = true, $separator = ' &raquo; ', $nicename = false, $visited = array()) {

$chain = '';

$parent = &get_term($id, $taxonomy);

if (is_wp_error($parent)) { echo "fail";
    return $parent;
}

if ($nicename)

    $name = $parent -> slug;

else

    $name = $parent -> name;

if ($parent -> parent && ($parent -> parent != $parent -> term_id) && !in_array($parent -> parent, $visited)) {

    $visited[] = $parent -> parent;

    $chain .= get_taxonomy_parents($parent -> parent, $taxonomy, $link, $separator, $nicename, $visited);

}

    if ( $link ) {
        // $chain .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $parent->term_id ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $parent->name ) ) . '">'.$name.'</a>' . $separator;
        $chain .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( (int) $parent->term_id, $taxonomy ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $parent->name ) ) . '">'.$name.'</a>' . $separator;
    } else {
        $chain .= $name.$separator;
    }
    return $chain;

}
```

Comment: » is an opening or closing quotation mark in many languages, screenreaders announce it as such. Misusing it as a separator is very unfriendly for those who rely on screenreaders. Don’t do that. Please edit the other post to include the fix if necessary.

Comment: I updated the original post with the $link fix (without the » separator).

Answer (score 0):

There is no deeper level function in `get_category_parents()` (see [source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/category-template.php#L30)). It just checks `parent` field in category object and then recursively checks for its parent until it runs out.

So you will need either to write simple analogue or rewrite it (depending on how much functionality you need).

Answer (score 0):

`get_the_terms` and `get_term` retrieve the parent ID amongst the term's data. So you could use that info to build a custom functions that will display the taxonomy tree.

I'm actually working on something similar - will post the code as soon as I have it working and clean ;-D

EDIT : I finally did it... Here is the code to get "topcat -> childcat -> yetchildcat" with link to the taxonomy term page:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->id, 'portfolio category' );
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) { 
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $tree = '<a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'portfolio category').'">'.$term->name.'</a>';
        $parents = get_ancestors( $term->term_id, 'portfolio category' );
        foreach ($parents as $parent) {
            $term = get_term($parent, 'portfolio category');
            $tree = '<a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'geo').'">'.$term->name.'</a> -> '.$tree;
       }
    echo $tree;
}
```

I'm sure it is possible to make better/cleaner code, but it seems to work ;-D

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a recursive function based almost exactly off of get_category_parents(), just replacing the category-specific parts with term-based equivalents.  Hope it helps someone.

```
// my own function to wo what get_category_parents does for other taxonomies
function get_taxonomy_parents($id, $taxonomy, $link = false, $separator = '/', $nicename = false, $visited = array()) {

$chain = '';

$parent = &get_term($id, $taxonomy);

if (is_wp_error($parent)) { echo "fail";
    return $parent;
}

if ($nicename)

    $name = $parent -> slug;

else

    $name = $parent -> name;

if ($parent -> parent && ($parent -> parent != $parent -> term_id) && !in_array($parent -> parent, $visited)) {

    $visited[] = $parent -> parent;

    $chain .= get_taxonomy_parents($parent -> parent, $taxonomy, $link, $separator, $nicename, $visited);

}

if ( $link ) {

    $chain .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( (int) $parent->term_id, $taxonomy ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $parent->name ) ) . '">'.$name.'</a>' . $separator;
} else {
    $chain .= $name.$separator;
}
return $chain;

}
```